# scala-json-rpc: value pretty is not a member of io.circe.Printer

Tags: json, scala, rpc, json-rpc, circe

i recently updated huge project from Scala 2.12 to 2.13 and switched form using
`https://github.com/shogowada/scala-json-rpc`
to:
`https://github.com/nawforce/scala-json-rpc`
And few methods - jsonRPCServer.{bindApi, receive} and jsonRPCClient.createAPI - started giving me this error:
`value pretty is not a member of io.circe.Printer`
It didn't appear in the former version of the library. I tried to examine the sources, but failed to find the problematic calls.
Do, by any chance, any of you had similiar problem?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at Scaladex and looking at the `circe` dependency for both packages ([Scaledex for the original](https://index.scala-lang.org/nawforce/scala-json-rpc), [Scaladex for the fork you are using](https://index.scala-lang.org/shogowada/scala-json-rpc)), it has been upgraded from 0.8.0 to 0.13.0. Looking at [this commit](https://github.com/circe/circe/pull/1240/files#diff-29d5b464593242150a323b723877ccad4b5be2c0eedb6772ccdcfb7a3d5059fbR117-R118) it looks like `pretty` has been deprecated in 0.12.0 (and judging from your post, probably dropped in 0.13.0) and replaced by `printWith`, which is likely what you want to use.